# How to use qt-gstreamer with qtquick2videosink on Qt5 on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: qt5, raspberry-pi3, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I built qt-gstreamer from source code on GitHub (version 1.2.0). Then I tried to run qmlplayer2 application (built from qt-gstreamer and use qtquick2videosink) on qt5 on Raspberry Pi3 but I got the following error at runtime:

> (gst-plugin-scanner:3749): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin
>   '/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstqt5videosink.so':
>   /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstqt5videosink.so: undefined symbol:
>   _Z33gst_qt_quick2_video_sink_get_typev    Failed to create qtquick2videosink. Make sure it is installed correctly
>
> (qmlplayer2:8517): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_add: assertion
>   'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
>
> (qmlplayer2:8517): GStreamer-CRITICAL **:
>   gst_element_link_pads_filtered: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (dest)'
>   failed

Answer (score 1):

Look at source code of qt-gstreamer, i found that the function gst_qt_quick2_video_sink_get_type() is implemented in gstqtquick2videosink.cpp but this file was not compiled due to missing configuration in cmake related to OpenGL.

I config cmake as below :

[image]

then rebuild and deploy new file libgstqt5videosink.so to /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstqt5videosink.so on target device. After that qmlplayer2 application work fine.

Comment: "Config as below"... Sorry, but config how? Did u forget to write your config

Comment: thank you for responding quickly, but I'm still having difficulties. I dont know how to update these variables in cmake. Im a cmake novice. Im using buildroot, I can see the above variables in the CMakeCache.txt after the configure stage, but I dont believe thats the correct way to update them. Please advice the best file(s) to update the paths. Thanks

Comment: @DMacAttach you should use Cmake GUI instead of command line to easy config these variables

Comment: thanks for the update & the fix. I patched the CMakeLists.txt to add my paths.